# Нет вывода в консоле сервера Minecraft 1.18.2 Paper

Tags: сервер, minecraft

Установил Windows 10 от Flibuster и появилась проблема, запуская start.bat консоль полностью пустая и писать в неё ничего нельзя, но сервер при этом работает, в диспетчере задач появляется Java:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Консоль в это время вообще никакая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу понять с чем это связано, пробовал запускать от имени администратора, обыскал весь интернет, но пока ничего не помогло. Код в start.bat:

```
@echo off
title Новый проект
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.3\bin\javaw.exe" -Xms1024m -Xmx3060m -jar core.jar nogui
pause
```

Если убрать "nogui", запускается немного не то, что нужно.

Я заранее всех благодарю!

Comment: Извиняюсь, уточнение: До установки винды всё работало отлично, я делал те же самые действия и всё было хорошо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опечатка. `javaw` используется для того чтобы запустить приложение без консоли. Используйте `java`.

```
@echo off
title Новый проект
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.3\bin\java.exe" -Xms1024m -Xmx3060m -jar core.jar nogui
pause
```